Сhanging color of previously saved points (markers) in QGIS
How to change the color of previously saved points (markers) during the process of raster binding?
During the process of raster binding, we put a dot marker on one layer, and then on another. By default, this is a red dot. In the palette settings, I can assign a different color to the ready-made marker "dot red". But this will not be entirely correct - the red marker is a different color.
Maybe it is possible not to change the color of the red marker, but somehow assign the use of a marker of a different color for the markers of the raster binding dialog?
In addition, changing the color using this technology does not affect previously saved anchor points. It only affects new ones. How can I change the color of previously saved anchor points?

In which GIS you are working?

QGIS 3.34.7-Prizren
